# Combining 2 columns with different amount of rows and nothing in common in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 columns Date and Year. Under the date there are rows for every month in the year. In order to only show distinct values of the year column I replaced the duplicates with nulls but when I called that column in my report it just placed blank rows in between each year. This table is used strictly for the purposes of creating a list of parameters that can be used to filter the report.

Right now my table looks something like this:

```
Date        Year
-----------------
1/2013      2013
2/2013      2013
3/2013      2013
.
.
.
12/2013     2013
1/2014      2014
2/2014      2014
```

Here is what I would like the table to look like.

```
Date        Year
-----------------
1/2013      2013
2/2013      2014
3/2013      2015
.             .
.             .
.             .
12/2013       .
1/2014        .
2/2014        .
```

Here is the query I am using:

```
            SELECT  rmp.EcoDate as Date,
            year(rmp.EcoDate) as Year, 

            FROM      PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_542 AS rcl INNER JOIN
                      CaseCases AS cc ON rcl.CaseCaseId = cc.CaseCaseId INNER JOIN
                      PhdRpt.RptMonthlyProduction_542 AS rmp ON rcl.ReportRunCaseId = rmp.ReportRunCaseId
            GROUP BY rmp.EcoDate
```

Is the best way to accomplish this to create 2 temp tables and create a common field such a row and the join on that row or is there a cleaner way? At the end of the year column I expect to just have nulls to fill out the rest of the rows.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Basically, you want each date sequentially numbered? Why starting at 2013?

Comment: please say clearly what you want to do....

Comment: It doesn't necessarily start at 2013. It starts at the year of whatever the first date of the query is.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson If you notice in the query I am merely taking the year from the datetime column rmp.EcoDate however I need to get rid of repeating years while still preserving the data in the Date column.

Comment: @RolandP Something like `WITH cte AS (
  SELECT  rmp.EcoDate as Date,
          YEAR(rmp.EcoDate) - 1 +
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rmp.EcoDate) Year
  FROM RptMonthlyProduction_542 rmp
)
SELECT * FROM cte;`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That would be exactly what I needed if the years stopped at the least year of the ecodate. For example, if the dates were from 1/2011 - 1/2020 the year column would have 2011-2020 in your example, it just counted until the rows ended. Do I have to add a case when statement?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by grouping year and date in their own temp tables and then creating a common column using  row_number and then doing a full outer join with the first table to the second one. Here is the query:

```
SELECT      CAST(MONTH(rmp.EcoDate) AS Varchar(2)) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(rmp.EcoDate) AS varchar(4)) AS Date,  
            rmp.EcoDate as EcoDate,
            row_number() over ( order by rmp.ecodate) as seqnum
into #a
FROM         PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_542 AS rcl INNER JOIN
                      CaseCases AS cc ON rcl.CaseCaseId = cc.CaseCaseId INNER JOIN
                      PhdRpt.RptMonthlyProduction_542 AS rmp ON rcl.ReportRunCaseId = rmp.ReportRunCaseId
GROUP BY rmp.EcoDate

SELECT      year(rmp.EcoDate) as Year, 
            CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),YEAR(rmp.EcoDate) )) as EcoYear,
            row_number() over ( order by year(rmp.ecodate)) as seqnum
into #b
FROM         PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_542 AS rcl INNER JOIN
          CaseCases AS cc ON rcl.CaseCaseId = cc.CaseCaseId INNER JOIN
          PhdRpt.RptMonthlyProduction_542 AS rmp ON rcl.ReportRunCaseId = rmp.ReportRunCaseId
GROUP BY year(rmp.EcoDate)

 Select *
 From #a a
 Full Outer Join #b b on a.seqnum = b.seqnum

 drop table #a, #b
```